# Nextcloud on Raspberry Pi via docker compose

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, pi, nextcloud

I'm trying to run a Nextcloud instance on my Raspbery Pi 3B+ using a docker-compose file from this source: https://blog.ssdnodes.com/blog/installing-nextcloud-docker/

This works out of the box without any issues on a Ubuntu Server.
I've replaced the following images to be compatible with the arm infrastructure of the Pi:

- `jwilder/nginx-proxy:alpine` with `braingamer/nginx-proxy-arm` or `budry/jwilder-nginx-proxy-arm` (I tried both)
- `jrcs/letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion` with `budry/jrcs-letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion-arm`
- `mariadb` with `linuxserver/mariadb`
- `nextcloud:latest` with `linuxserver/nextcloud`

Unfortunately this doesn't work on the Pi, the Pi returns first a `502 Bad Gateway`, then after some time the error `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS`.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

My docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'

services:

  proxy:
    image: braingamer/nginx-proxy-arm
    labels:
      - "com.github.jrcs.letsencrypt_nginx_proxy_companion.nginx_proxy=true"
    container_name: nextcloud-proxy
    networks:
      - nextcloud_network
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    volumes:
      - ./proxy/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d:rw
      - ./proxy/vhost.d:/etc/nginx/vhost.d:rw
      - ./proxy/html:/usr/share/nginx/html:rw
      - ./proxy/certs:/etc/nginx/certs:ro
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro
    restart: unless-stopped

  letsencrypt:
    image: budry/jrcs-letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion-arm
    container_name: nextcloud-letsencrypt
    depends_on:
      - proxy
    networks:
      - nextcloud_network
    volumes:
      - ./proxy/certs:/etc/nginx/certs:rw
      - ./proxy/vhost.d:/etc/nginx/vhost.d:rw
      - ./proxy/html:/usr/share/nginx/html:rw
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
    restart: unless-stopped

  db:
    image: linuxserver/mariadb
    container_name: nextcloud-mariadb
    networks:
      - nextcloud_network
    volumes:
      - db:/var/lib/mysql
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
    environment:
      - PUID=1000
      - PGID=1000
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=***PASSWORD***
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=***PASSWORD***
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=nextcloud
      - MYSQL_USER=nextcloud
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    restart: unless-stopped

  app:
    image: linuxserver/nextcloud
    container_name: nextcloud-app
    networks:
      - nextcloud_network
    depends_on:
      - letsencrypt
      - proxy
      - db
    volumes:
      - nextcloud:/var/www/html
      - ./app/config:/var/www/html/config
      - ./app/custom_apps:/var/www/html/custom_apps
      - ./app/data:/var/www/html/data
      - ./app/themes:/var/www/html/themes
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
    environment:
      - PUID=1000
      - PGID=1000
      - TZ=Europe/London
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=nextcloud.domain.tld
      - LETSENCRYPT_HOST=nextcloud.domain.tld
      - LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL=mail@nextcloud.domain.tld

volumes:
  nextcloud:
  db:

networks:
  nextcloud_network:
```

Comment: Did you solve your issue? If not, could you post output of `docker-compose logs proxy` and contents of your nginx configuration?

Answer (score 0):

The [tutorial](https://blog.ssdnodes.com/blog/installing-nextcloud-docker/) used a Nginx reverse proxy and Let’s Encrypt, for the latter you need a valid domain. If you look at your compose file for linuxserver/nextcloud under environment, it asks for a domain for VIRTUAL_HOST, LETSENCRYPT_HOST and LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL. It then tries to create a ssl certificate for the specified domain (nextcloud.domain.tld), which is not valid, so it doesn't work.
This was the case for me, so I just removed the proxy and ssl from my compose file and nextcloud works now :)

Here is my current working compose file:

```
version: '3'

services:

  db:
    image: tobi312/rpi-mariadb:10.5
    container_name: nextcloud-mariadb
    networks:
      - nextcloud_network
    volumes:
      - db:/var/lib/mysql
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=very_secure_password
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=very_secure_password
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=nextcloud
      - MYSQL_USER=nextcloud
    restart: unless-stopped

  app:
    image: nextcloud:latest
    container_name: nextcloud-app
    networks:
      - nextcloud_network
    depends_on:
      - db
    volumes:
      - nextcloud:/var/www/html
      - ./app/config:/var/www/html/config
      - ./app/custom_apps:/var/www/html/custom_apps
      - ./app/data:/var/www/html/data
      - ./app/themes:/var/www/html/themes
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - 80:80

volumes:
  nextcloud:
  db:

networks:
  nextcloud_network:
    driver: bridge
```

Hope it helps.